# TimeSpan to String causing an error

Tags: c#

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(124432492); // I am giving ticks here.
string duration = timeSpan.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff");
```

Conversion gives

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Something is not right and i can't see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of "HH:mm:ss:fff" use "HH:MM:ss:fff"

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov `MM` is months, not minutes. Anyway for `Timespan` there´s no `MM` defined.

Comment: The fractional-element is `"fffffff"` as of the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: When I use DateTime it's working, but when i try TimeSpan it's not working.

Comment: @HimBromBeere you are right

Comment: That is because DateTime and TimeSpan doesn't use the exact same custom formats. In particular, the colons needs to be escaped for TimeSpan.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks for the tip, i didn't know that.

Comment: The formaters for `DateTime` are not equivalent to those of `Timespan`. In particular for the latter `"fff"` is not a valid format-string, only `"fffffff"` is allowed.